# How do I arrange/sort the bookmarks in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, chromium

I am facing a wierd issue where I cannot arrange the bookmarks on my bookmarks bar.

I have three items Old (Folder), Samles (Link), Firefox (Folder).

I want to have folders first and then links, as in Windows explorer (Folders first and files).

But as soon as I drag to arrange, they automatically shift themselves into original position.

Comment: Dev/beta/stable? Version number? OS? Works OK for me on V8.0.552.224 stable on WinXP.

Comment: Same version number as yours, happening on Ubuntu .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed this by disabling the bookmark sync options in `chrome://chrome/settings/syncSetup`.